Displaying Only Newly Added Data into Email's Message Content Using SharePoint's "When an item or a file is modified" trigger
I'm looking into sending an email that contains ONLY the newly added data from the excel file. The data in the excel file is illustrated in the following screenshot below:
Excel Sheet
So for example, the newly added data into the excel file are ['Key'] = 1235, ['Date'] = 9 July 2024 and ['Level'] = Red1, illustrated in a red circle in the screenshot below:
Newly Added Data in Excel Sheet
The issue is that I'm not sure how to derive it as a condition in the "Filter Array" action such that if the latest newly added data in the ['Key'] column (denoted as 1235 in a red circle in the above screenshot) is greater than the previous data (denoted as 1234 located in the second row in the screenshot above) and then send email with the newly added data of ['Key'], ['Date'] and ['Level'].
My Power Automate flow is attached as image below:
Power Automate Flow
Therefore the scenario is, whenever there is a newly added data into the excel file, it would trigger the flow to run in Power Automate through using the SharePoint's "When an item or a file is modified".  Referring to the screenshot that was marked with a red circle, after that a condition would be derived in the "Filter Array" action such that if the latest newly added data in the ['Key'] column (denoted as 1235 in a red circle in the above screenshot) is greater than the previous data (denoted as 1234 located in the second row in the screenshot above), then it would proceed to send ONLY the newly added data in the email. Really need help on this, thanks!
